# Why does an undefined variable in Javascript sometimes evaluate to false and sometimes throw an uncaught ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript

Everything I've ever read indicates that in Javascript, the boolean value of an undefined variable is False. I've used code like this hundreds of times:

```
if (!elem) {
   ...
}
```

with the intent that if "elem" is undefined, the code in the block will execute. It usually works, but on occasion the browser will throw an error complaining about the undefined reference. This seems so basic, but I can't find the answer.

Is it that there's a difference between a variable that has not been defined and one that has been defined but which has a value of undefined? That seems completely unintuitive.

Comment: Just came here and want to leave a comment about 'hoisting'. If you declare the variable elem after your check and in the same function (scope) you will have a value of undefined from top of the function until you pass some value to it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### What is a ReferenceError?

As defined by ECMAScript 5, a [`ReferenceError`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.11.6.3) indicates that an invalid reference has been detected. That doesn't say much by itself, so let's dig a little deeper.

Leaving aside strict mode, a `ReferenceError` occurs when the scripting engine is instructed to get the value of a reference that it [cannot resolve the *base value*](http://es5.github.com/#IsUnresolvableReference) for:

> A Reference is a resolved name binding. A Reference consists of three
>   components, the base value, the referenced name and the Boolean valued
>   strict reference flag. The base value is either undefined, an Object,
>   a Boolean, a String, a Number, or an environment record (10.2.1). A
>   base value of undefined indicates that the reference could not be
>   resolved to a binding. The referenced name is a String.

When we are referencing a property, the base value is the object whose property we are referencing. When we are referencing a variable, the base value is unique for each execution context and it's called an *environment record*. When we reference something that is neither a property of the base object value nor a variable of the base environment record value, a `ReferenceError` occurs.

Consider what happens when you type `foo` in the console when no such variable exists: you get a `ReferenceError` because the *base value* is *not resolvable*. However, if you do `var foo; foo.bar` then you get a `TypeError` instead of a `ReferenceError` -- a subtle perhaps but very significant difference. This is because the *base value* was successfully resolved; however, it was of type `undefined`, and `undefined` does not have a property `bar`.

### Guarding against ReferenceError

From the above it follows that to catch a ReferenceError before it occurs you have to make sure that the base value is resolvable. So if you want to check if `foo` is resolvable, do

```
if(this.foo) //...
```

In the global context, `this` equals the `window` object so doing `if (window.foo)` is equivalent. In other execution contexts it does not make as much sense to use such a check because by definition it's an execution context your own code has created -- so you should be aware of which variables exist and which do not.

Answer (score 6):

Checking for undefined works for variables that have no value associated but if the variable itself hasn't been declared you can run into these reference issues.

```
if (typeof elem === "undefined")
```

This is a far better check as doesn't run the risk of the reference issue as typeof isn't a method but a keyword within JavaScript.

Comment: That's what I wind up doing, but that's not really enough; in many cases you also need to check for null or "", so you wind up with something really ugly like "if (typeof x === 'undefined' || !x)..."

Comment: I'm not really sure what elem is but what you describe isn't really typical. Having to check for undefined, null and empty is a bit and probably depends what you're working with.

Comment: `typeof isn't a method but a keyword within JavaScript.`
not really, `typeof` is an operator not a keyword, unlike `var` or `let` which are keywords, mostly used to tell JS to allocate memory for some sort of holding a pointer/reference.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it that there's a difference between a variable that has not been defined and one that has been defined but which has a value of undefined?

**Yes**. A undeclared variable will throw a `ReferenceError` when used in an expression, which is what you're seeing.

```
if (x) { // error, x is undeclared

}
```

Compared to;

```
var y; // alert(y === undefined); // true

if (y) { // false, but no error

}
```

> That seems completely unintuitive.

**Meh**... what I find unintuitive:

```
if (y) // error, y is undeclared

var x = {};

if (x.someUndeclaredAttribute) // no error... someUndeclaredAttribute is implictly undefined.
```

Comment: Yet more unintuitive is the global variable case: `foo` throws a ReferenceError, while `window.foo` evaluates to false.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of [Jon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon) explanation regarding environment records:

```
var bar = function bar() {
    if (!b) { // will throw a reference error.
    }
},
foo = function foo() {
    var a = false;

    if (a) {
        var b = true;
    }

    if (!b) { // will not throw a reference error.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In strict mode, it is an error:

```
function a() {
  "use strict";
  if (!banana) alert("no banana"); // throws error
}
```

It's always really been better to make an explicit test for globals:

```
if (!window['banana']) alert("no banana");
```

It doesn't make sense to perform such a test for non-global variables. (That is, testing to see whether the variable is defined that way; it's fine to test to see whether a defined variable has a truthy value.)

*edit* I'll soften that to say that it *rarely* makes sense to thusly test for the existence of non-globals.

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is declared and not initialized or it's used with declaration, its value is "undefined". The browser complains exactly when this undefined variable is referenced. Here "reference" means some piece of javascript code is trying to visit an attribute or method of it. For example, if "elem" is undefined, this will throw an exception:

```
elem.id = "BadElem";
```

Answer (score 0):

or you use try/catch:

```
try { x } catch(err){}
```

This way you're not doing anything in case of an error but at least your script won't jump off the cliff...

Answer (score 0):

undefined = variable exists but has no value in it

ReferenceError = variable does not exist