# checking for undefined in javascript-- should I use typeof or not?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm a bit confused about how best to check if a variable is undefined or not in javascript.  I've been doing it like this:

```
myVar === undefined;
```

But is it better in all cases to use typeof instead?

```
typeof myVar === undefined;
```

And what about the use of `undefined` vs `"undefined"`, which I've also seen?

Comment: `typeof` returns a string, so you should compare its result to `"undefined"` if you use the strict comparison operator.

Comment: If you only want to know if `myVar` has a non-falsy value, `!` would suffice. (e.g. `if(!myVar)`

Comment: @ Frédéric Hamidi-- thank you for the explanation.  Do you use (or recommend) using typeof in most circumstances?  In all circumstances?   I ask because I've seen `myVar === undefined` used in reputable books, which is why I've been using it.

Comment: @larryq, `myVar === undefined` is not the same thing as `typeof myVar === "undefined"`. The first syntax will throw an exception if `myVar` does not exist in the current scope. See the potential duplicate for the full story.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of 'typeof === "undefined" vs. != null'. The similarity is superficial. Please read carefully before you cast those Close votes, folks.

Comment: @dgvid, how not? `!= null` and `!= undefined` behave the same, and IMHO the answers in the duplicate match this question quite well.

Comment: `!= null` and `!= undefined` *often* behave the same way, but not always. And although it's true that the two questions have nearly duplicate answers, most people don't arrive at Stack Overflow with answers, they come here with questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the best way to check -- totally foolproof:

```
typeof myVar === "undefined"
```

This is OK, but it could fail if someone unhelpfully overwrote the global `undefined` value:

```
myVar === undefined;
```

It has to be said that ECMAScript 5 specifies that `undefined` is read-only, so the above will always be safe in any browser that conforms.

This will never work because it ends up comparing `"undefined" === undefined` (different types):

```
typeof myVar === undefined;
```

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer?  AFAIK, attempting to access an undefined memory space will always throw an ReferenceError in both ES5 and ES6: https://jsfiddle.net/Troop4Christ/on2oynvz/ and http://www.es6fiddle.net/ijls28o5/

Comment: @RavenHursT: That's not the point of this question -- although granted, the example code given in the question is not the best. It's more like what happens [here](https://jsfiddle.net/on2oynvz/1/). Regarding `ReferenceError`, there is at least [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9981104/50079) that covers it which I know about because I have an answer there too.

Answer (score 2):

This test would always work as expected:

```
typeof a === 'undefined'
```

Since the value of `undefined` can be changed, tests like these aren't always reliable:

```
a = {}
a.b === undefined
```

In those cases you could test against `void 0` instead:

```
a.b === void 0
// true
```

However, this won't work for single variable tests:

```
a === void 0 // <-- error: cannot find 'a'
```

You could work around that by testing against `window.a`, but the first method should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the most common cases, e.g. when checking if a parameter is passed through a function, `myVar === undefined` is enough, as myVar will be always declared as a parameter