# Insert value into a Javascript array randomly

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I created a table using an 8x8 matrix for a game and i also put into the table prizes, and etc in random places but I am having an issue creating also random start position for the user that doesn't conflict with the objects that are already in the table.

For now I have:

```
function startPos(matrix) {
  var x = Math.round(Math.random() * matrix.length);
  var y = Math.round(Math.random() * matrix.length);

  while (matrix[y][x] != undefined) {
    var x = Math.round(Math.random() * matrix.length);
    var y = Math.round(Math.random() * matrix.length);
    return matrix[y][x];
  };


  return matrix[y][x];
};
```

but I get nothing. Sorry if the question seems trivial I am just starting Javascript and have looked everywhere for a relevant answer with no avail.

Comment: the problem is that you're `return`ing on the first iteration of your `while` loop. If you remove that `return`, then your `while` loop will iterate until it finds an `x` and `y` that work, then the loop will end and your code will hit the final `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is select a random position in the matrix, if it is undefined then return it, otherwise select a new random position and try again. You need to make a few changes for this.

**First** - the return statement in your loop is unnecessary and is causing your function to be returned on the first run of the loop, stopping it from doing its job.

**Second** - In most cases, you should use `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`. You can find a detailed explanation here - [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons/359509#359509)

**Third** - When you want to check if a variable is undefined, while `myVar === undefined` should work most of the time, there a situations where it could fail. best practice is to use `typeof myVar === 'undefined'`. More info here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15093969/7739148

try this:

```
function startPos(matrix){
  // first select a random position
  var x = Math.round(Math.random() * matrix.length);
  var y = Math.round(Math.random() * matrix.length);

  // if the position is not empty, select a new one.
  // continue like this until an empty spot is found.
  while(typeof matrix[y][x] !== 'undefined'){
    x = Math.round(Math.random() * matrix.length);
    y = Math.round(Math.random() * matrix.length);
  };

  // once we have an empty position, return it
  return matrix[y][x];
};
```

Caution - if there are no positions that are undefined the loop will never end, so you should either make sure your matrix will have at least one empty spot, or perform a check at the start of your function.

Comment: `typeof … !== undefined` is always true

Comment: "*the value of x and y are never changed […] you are creating new variables that only exist within the scope of your loop*" - Nope. `var` has function scope

Comment: oops! meant to put `typeof x === 'undefined'` with undefined as a string. And you are correct about the function scoping. I have edited my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

A few mistakes:

- you must not `return` from within the loop, but have to check the condition to leave it
- you need to use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`
- you need to return the position, not the value of the field (which you just asserted to be `undefined`)

```
function startPos(matrix) {
  var l = matrix.length; // assumes square matrix
  do { // assumes at least one empty field
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);
  } while (matrix[y][x] != undefined);
  return [y, x];
}
```