# Querying for non existent property doesn't always throw error

Tags: javascript

Why when executing this piece of code, only checking for `thisThrowsError` actually throws error, but querying for non existent property on the prototype object or on `this` context doesn't?

```
function Test()
{

    if(this.someVar){}
    if(Test.prototype.someVar){}  
    if(thisThrowsError){}
 }

var test = new Test();
```

Comment: Because there is no dot in thisThrowsError? Simply testing if a property exists does not throw an error. Trying to use a non-existent property will.

Comment: You're not querying for a **property**. You're querying for a **variable**. Trying to access a variable that isn't defined will throw an exception. If you want to check for **existence** of a **property** of an object, you can use `"property" in object` or `object.hasOwnProperty("property")`. If you want to check for **existence** of a **variable** safely, use `typeof variable !== "undefined"`. If you want to check if an object's property is `undefined`, just use `object.property === undefined`

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. Another one for your list: undefined arguments don't throw errors e.g. function Test(a){if(a){}}; Test();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Why does an undefined variable in Javascript sometimes evaluate to false and sometimes throw an uncaught ReferenceError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981104/why-does-an-undefined-variable-in-javascript-sometimes-evaluate-to-false-and-som)

Comment: So it's safe to just use simple `if(object.property)` to test for existence. And for variable references I need to use `if(typeof thisThrowsError !="undefined")`?

Comment: You should be able to check for variable existence with `this.theVariable` as far as I know. At least in the global context. See the linked question, it explores this.

Comment: @IvanV. No, you can't. Because `if` statements will evaluate the property...meaning that if the **value** is `false`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, or `null`, it won't work properly.

Comment: Oh yes, duh. Existence and non-falsiness then…

Comment: I've read the link you posted, and I makes much more sense. 
What I was trying to do is to test for existence of some values.
In all three cases if statements won't be executed. First two statements will resolve to undefined, and the third one will throw a reference error.
The accepted answer on the link you posted very well explains why.
What I'm getting at right now is that if I want to test for a variable existence I need to test with the `typeof` operator.

Comment: @IvanV. To test for a **local variable existence**, you have to use `typeof variable !== "undefined"`. If you want to test **global variable existence**, you can use `"variable" in window` or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, "variable")`