# Javascript namespace initialization pattern requires `var` or `window.`

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I came across this pattern for JavaScript initialization:

```
foo = foo || {};
alert('no errors!');
```

But it seems that it does not work unless `foo` was defined before.

There are two variations of the same pattern that seem to work correctly:

```
var foo = foo || {};
alert('no errors!');
```

and

```
foo = window.foo || {};
alert('no errors!');
```

From my point of view, I don't understand why the first one does not work, but the two other do.

Why is that? Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does an undefined variable in Javascript sometimes evaluate to false and sometimes throw an uncaught ReferenceError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981104/why-does-an-undefined-variable-in-javascript-sometimes-evaluate-to-false-and-som)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has a `global object`. In the browser, this is referenced by the name `window`.

`window.foo` create a property in the global object.

`var foo` create a global variable.  This is very similar to a property of the global object, but you can't use `delete` on it.

Simply declaring `foo` without the `var` keyword also create a property on the global object.  It is a language design choice -- a lousy one -- but a design choice none-the-less.

`var foo` and `window.foo` both work equally well when you are at the global level.  If you are inside of a function -- perhaps a module -- you *must* use `window.foo` to make sure you reach the global object.

Comment: So you are saying that even when I use `window.foo` on the right-hand side of the assignment, it still creates the `window.foo` variable with the value of `undefined`?

Comment: No, it creates a `property` on the `window` object.  To create a variable you use `var.`  However -- when you access a property of *any* object that doesn't exist, you get the value of `undefined.`  So ... `window.XYZZYFOOBAR` will be undefined because it doesn't exist.

Comment: OK, I understand it now. The problem was undeclared `foo`. The reason why first alternative was working was because it declared it, the reason why second alternative was working because accessing non-existing property does not cause an `ReferenceError` as it does on non-declared variable. Thank you.

Comment: Bingo! You've got it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read a variable which isn't defined ([that's a reference error](http://es5.github.io/#IsUnresolvableReference)). That's why

```
something = foo;
```

will lead to an error if the `foo` variable isn't declared. `window` is declared of course and there's no problem querying its *property* `foo`.

Comment: You can read a variable that is not defined, you can't read one that is not *declared*.

Comment: @Quentin You mean a variable whose *value* isn't defined. But I change the wording to be less ambiguous.