# JavaScript, Hoisting between 'var' and without 'var'

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I understand the following function because variable hoisting happens.
foo();

```
function foo() {
    console.log( a ); // undefined
    var a = 2;
}
```

However what I don't understand is the following part. 
I got Reference Error, why?

```
foo()
function foo() {
    console.log( a ); // Reference Error
    a = 2;
}
```

--- Edit ---
So far, what I understand from the answers is the second does not make any hoisting and we cannot use any undefined variable.

```
foo()
function foo() {
    //  we cannot use any undefined variable, which "a" here 
    console.log( a ); 
    window.a = 2;
}
```

For example

```
var a;
a; //undefined
b; //Reference error
```

Comment: As there is no `var` declaration, it'll not be hoisted, and it is defined in Global space **after** log statement, so throwing error

Comment: What else would you have expected?

Comment: @Bergi `undefined` _maybe_

Comment: @Bergi I don't think the _so dupe_ answers the question, that is related to Global/Local scope, this is related to hoisting.

Comment: @Tushar: Do you think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9981152/1048572) would be a better dupe?

Comment: @Bergi, if you think this is dupe and better to be removed, I will delete it. I got good anderstanding from Tushar, thanks to him

Comment: Main thing to note here is that **variables declared without `var` are not hoisted**, and an undeclared variable throws Reference Error.

Comment: @allenhwkim: No, closing doesn't mean that it's better to be removed, please keep it. It just seemed to already be answered there, at either of the two linked questions.

Comment: @Tushar: You meant to say "variables *defined* without `var` are not *declared*"? :-)

Comment: @Bergi No, I'd say this question should not be removed, this'll help peoples understand why the code is working like this and will avoid asking same question in future.

Comment: @Bergi _"variables defined without var are not declared"?_, I said **hoisted** :)

Comment: @Tushar: I see what you've said, I was just nitpicking that a variable without `var` is not *declared* (unless it's a function, parameter etc) - and are not hoisted either, of course.

Comment: @allenhwkim: No, it's not the function call that throws the `ReferenceError`. It's the expression `a` or `b` itself that throws when evaluated - try `a; b;` (without any `foo(…)`)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, edited it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, `a` is declared, but `undefined`, in the second it's also also *undeclared* (can't be found in `foo` or in global scope), so throws a ReferenceError.