# CSS variable with fallback value of itself

Tags: css, css-variables

What I'm trying to achieve in javascript will look like this:

```
myVar = newVar || myVar;
```

In css I'm doing the following:

```
--my-var: var(--new-var, var(--my-var))
```

Seems like it does not work. Is it even possible to have an old value in fallback if new value is undefined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally CSS can't do *if/then/else*, but when using i.e. `var` one can, kind of.

> Using var() you can define a fallback value when the given
>   variable is not yet defined

The second (optional) argument, the *declaration-value*, has some limits though.

> The  production matches any sequence of one or more
>   tokens.  So, as long as the sequence does not contain
>   , , unmatched <)-token>, <]-token>,
>   or <}-token>, or top-level  tokens or 
>   tokens with a value of "!" ,it represents the entirety of what a valid
>   declaration can have as its value.

Src:

- [MDN CSS Var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)
- [MDN Using CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)

This won't work

```css
:root{ 
  --myOld: lime;
  --myVar: var(--myNew, --myOld) 
}

div {
  color: var(--myVar)
}
```

```html
<div>Hey there</div>
```

This will work

```css
:root{ 
  --myOld: lime;
  --myVar: var(--myNew, var(--myOld)) 
}

div {
  color: var(--myVar)
}
```

```html
<div>Hey there</div>
```

And this will work

```css
:root{ 
  --myVar: var(--myNew, var(--myOld, red)) 
}

div {
  color: var(--myVar)
}
```

```html
<div>Hey there</div>
```

---

For javascript, doing like that you get a reference error, and to avoid that you can do like this:

```
myVar = (typeof newVar === 'undefined') ? myVar : newVar;
```

Src: [Why does an undefined variable in Javascript sometimes evaluate to false and sometimes throw an uncaught ReferenceError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981104/why-does-an-undefined-variable-in-javascript-sometimes-evaluate-to-false-and-som)

Comment: @ZuzEL That is perfectly fine

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign the value of a custom property as a fallback value in a `var()` expression when redeclaring the same custom property. The old value is overridden during cascade resolution, so there would be no old value left to fall back to by the time the `var()` expression is evaluated.