# Unable to overwrite CSS variable with its own value

Tags: css, css-variables, css-calc

Lets assume to have the following CSS:

```css
.box {
  width: var(--box-size);
  height: var(--box-size);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box--larger {
  --box-size: 66px;
}

.box--larger1 {
  --box-size: calc(var(--box-size) + var(--box--larger));
}

.box--larger2 {
  --box-size: calc(50px + var(--box--larger));
}

:root {
  --box-size: 50px; 
  --box--larger: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box box--larger">2</div>
<div class="box box--larger1">3</div>
<div class="box box--larger2">4</div>
```

I wonder why boxes 1 and 2 work but box 3 doesn't. I would expect box 3 to look the same as box 2 but it doesn't. I tested box 3's approach in Chrome and I found that `var(--box-size)` doesn't show a value but `var(--box-larger)` does return the right value (16px).

Could someone explain why the approach of box 3 doesn't work. I mean to me it looks like valid CSS.

Comment: How do you import css file in you html?

Comment: @AlesandroGiordano I don't see how that is relevant but just with the normal approach: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">`. Both variables are in the same file as is in the example above.

Comment: Some time css is saved in cache of your project if you example are working with servlets... can you tell me in which contex are you using this html file?

Comment: I know HTML and CSS can be cached but I always refresh the cache on page reload using a clear cache plugin. The HTML is now in Laravel blade and the CSS part of a framework I'm making. However if it was due to cache than I guess it should have worked in the SO snippet but it didn't.

Comment: If you are able to get date informations you can try to add them to the css url, i’ll write you an answer, let me know if it can be helpful

Comment: CSS is not a functional language. It doesn't calculate those values the way you would expect of a regular programming language. Basically you are trying to tell the system, "the value of this item is the same as its value plus 16", which is confusing.

Comment: @AlesandroGiordano Why are you convinced that the outcome in the snippet here is the result of css caching? Snippets don't even use CSS files, they have <style> elements.

Comment: @MrLister that is extactly what I'm trying to do yes. But how can it be that "confusing" I mean the value is already defined you just overwrite it in a specific class. For box 3 and 4 you basically do the same thing except one works the other doesn't

Comment: You may want to just use a preprocessor in this case.

Comment: @SuperDJ Yes, but none of the other examples try to tell the system that the value of X is 16 greater than the value of X. I'm afraid you will have to use more variables.

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I'm already using a preprocessor but I still like to use CSS variables and calc. I only want to use the preprocessor as a last resort

Comment: @SuperDJ I see. I've been looking all over and can't seem to find good examples on _why_ it doesn't work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562399/css-variable-with-fallback-value-of-itself#answer-44563243) answer may provide a bit of insight even though it's relating to variable fallbacks.

Comment: as @MrLister said : CSS is not C++, full stop ... you have cycle dependency

Comment: As a reminder re: @ChaseIngebritson's comment, you can't do anything with a CSS preprocessor that you can't also do in CSS. It just lets you save some time when writing really long, repetitive CSS styles.

Comment: @SuperDJ It is confusing to CSS because CSS sees a recursive declaration the way you've written it, and CSS cannot handle recursion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As commented above, CSS is not C++ and you are having a cyclic dependency wanting to express a property with the same property which will not work.

Refering to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#cycles):

> Custom properties are left almost entirely unevaluated, except that
> they allow and evaluate the var() function in their value. This can
> create cyclic dependencies **where a custom property uses a var()**
> **referring to itself, or two or more custom properties each attempt to**
> **refer to each other.**

A common fix to that situation is to add more variables to avoid any cyclic dependency.

```css
:root {
  --bs:50px;
  --bl:16px;
  --box-size:var(--bs); 
  --box--larger:var(--bl);
}

.box {
  width: var(--box-size);
  height: var(--box-size);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box--larger {
  --box-size: 66px;
}

.box--larger1 {
  --box-size: calc(var(--bs) + var(--bl));
}

.box--larger2 {
  --box-size: calc(50px + var(--bl));
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box box--larger">2</div>
<div class="box box--larger1">3</div>
<div class="box box--larger2">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, similar approach - assigning the new value to another variable, but when you read it to use it - you fallback to the original value.

```css
:root {
 --box-size: 50px;
}
.box--large {
  --box-size-modified: calc(var(--box-size) * 2);
}

.box--huge {
  --box-size-modified: calc(var(--box-size) * 3);
}

.box {
  --box-size-to-use: var(--box-size-modified, var(--box-size))
  width: var(--box-size-to-use);
  height: var(--box-size-to-use);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here

```css
--box-size-to-use: var(--box-size-modified, var(--box-size))
```

creates a new variable from `--box-size-modified`. If it is not defined, it will fallback to the next value - `--box-size`.

With this - `.box` would be 50px, `.box.box--large` would be 100px and `.box.box--huge` would be 150px. But still, this would only give you 1 degree of freedom. If you want to go further, you would have to use more fallback values.