# CSS custom properties dependencies not resolving, why? Also, did I discover undocumented behavior?

Tags: css, css-variables

I believe the first two examples should have a green background and I believe the last example should fail because supplying another `var()` function as the first parameter is not defined behavior in the docs https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#cycles

```css
.test1 {
  --c1: green;
}
.test2 {
  --c1: var(--c1,red);
  background-color: var(--c1,pink);
}

.test3 {
  --c2: green;
}
.test4 {
  background-color: var(--c2,pink);
}

.test5 {
  --c3: green;
}
.test6 {
  --c3: var(var(--c3),red);
  background-color: var(--c3,pink);
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2">
    12
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test3">
  <div class="test4">
    34
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test5">
  <div class="test6">
    56
  </div>
</div>
```

Question 1:
Why is example "12" not working?

Question 2:
Why is example "56" working and should it be?

Comment: duplicate of the first question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51660196/8620333

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find that question. It is indeed a duplicate. Should I delete this?

Comment: no it can also be useful, we still have few questions around CSS variable so having many *similar* ones written differently can be helpful to bring search result

Answer (score 0):

After closely inspecting the developer tools and how the rules are evaluated I've decided to answer my own question.

Example "12" is not working because when you declare `--c1: var(--c1,red);` it immediately overrules its old value due to cascading rules, so the internal reference to `--c1` refers to the same line and generates a cycle, and the documentation states that:

> If there is a cycle in the dependency graph, all the custom
>   properties in the cycle must compute to their initial value (which is
>   a guaranteed-invalid value).

Example "56" appears to be working but it is not actually working, rule `--c3: var(var(--c3),red);` is completely invalid and is ignored, therefore example "56" acts identically to example "34".

Comment: still curious about CSS variables I see ;)